# Layout not working in IE 11, works well in most browsers

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, layout, windows-7

I have a pretty complex layout for my calendar script at    http://www.clinde.de/cal/index.php and i used http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage this IE Tester. It works like it should in all IE version exerpt 5.5 and that's really impressive. If i use my IE 11 on Win7/64bit the hover effect is bugged. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Any suggestions to improve this to make it work in IE 11?

Comment: This is intresting, it is not reproduceable in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J2gs5/ there must be a bug in stylesheet.

Comment: can you make a new class like `table.cal a.tag:hover{background:#e0e0e0}`; let us know if that work?

Comment: That does work. It's now the same in my IE11 as in Chrome and Firefox. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I also found this http://jsbin.com/zodarimi/9/edit solution to make <a href> fill a <div>.  Only thing this solution doesn't work with vertical-align:middle. What can you do about it?

Comment: For parent use `display:table` and for child element use `display:table-cell` with `vertical-align:middle`

Comment: You're awesome, that works very well. That removes some clutter from my code.